# Don't run validation on schema under certain conditions

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a schema with several required fields. When I save a document with a `published:false` prop, I want to **not** run any validation and just save the document as is. Later, when `published:true`, I want to run all the validation.

I thought this would work:

```
MySchema.pre('validate', function(next) {
    if(this._doc.published === false) {
        //don't run validation
        next();
    }
    else {
        this.validate(next);
    }
});
```

But this isn't working, it returns validation errors on required properties.

So how do I not run validation in some scenarios and run it in others? What's the most elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this one,

```
TagSchema.pre('validate', function(next) {
    if (!this.published)
        next();
    else {
        var error = new mongoose.Error.ValidationError(this);
        next(error);
    }
});
```

Test schema

```
var TagSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {type: String, require: true},
    published: Boolean,
    tags: [String]
});
```

With `published` is `true`

```
var t = new Tag({
    published: true,
    tags: ['t1']
});

t.save(function(err) {
    if (err)
        console.log(err);
    else
        console.log('save tag successfully...');
});
```

Result:

```
{ [ValidationError: Tag validation failed]
  message: 'Tag validation failed',
  name: 'ValidationError',
  errors: {} }
```

With `published` is `false`, result is

```
save tag successfully...
```